# How to run an exe file from gradle build during execution phase (Windows)

Tags: android, windows, gradle

I need to run an exe file during the execution phase of the build.

I know I can define something like this:

```
task executeScript(type:Exec) {
    println 'Executing script...'
    commandLine './script.sh'
}
```

But this is running the script during configuration phase.
I tried to wrap the code with a doLast block:

```
task executeScript(type:Exec) {
    doLast {
        println 'Executing script...'
        commandLine './script.sh'
    }
}
```

But this return an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyAssets'.
> execCommand == null!
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can define something like this:
>
> ```
> task executeScript(type:Exec) {
>     println 'Executing script...'
>     commandLine './script.sh'
> }
> ```

Your first attempt was actually correct. Your message will be printed during the configuration phase, since the `println` call is evaluated when the task `executeScript` is configured, but the script itself is not executed until the task executes.

If you want to print a message before the task executes, try the following:

```
task executeScript(type:Exec) {
    commandLine './script.sh'
    doFirst {
        println 'Executing script...'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank. And if I want to do something after the execution I should use the doLast correct? Also How do I get the error code of the script.

Comment: @Hanan For the `Exec` task type, it seems to work that way. I'm not sure whether there's a general guarantee that `doFirst` and `doLast` execute before and after the default task action of all built-in tasks, though, since the documentation doesn't seem to mention it anywhere.

If you want to access the exit code, access the [execResult](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:execResult) property of the task after the task has run, for example inside the `doLast` closure of a dependent task.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Now everything is working